# proof for this identity with infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was searching for a proof of the identity

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\tau}\tau^{n-1}}{n-1!}(1-\frac{\tau}{n}) \frac{\Gamma(1+n,\delta)}{\Gamma(1+n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\tau}\tau^{n-1}}{n-1!}  \frac{e^{-\delta}\delta^{n-1}}{n-1!}=e^{-\tau-\delta}I_0\left(2\sqrt{\tau\delta}\right)$$

I have already a proof that second and third term are equal, missing a proof connecting 1 to either 2, or 3.